# Slick Carousel creating massive white space to side, and not creating the carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

When I attempt to use slick carousel on my page it just creates a huge white space  to the right of the page, then pushes the content off to the right. I had used this exact code in codepen and it worked just fine then. Using the same scripts, but getting vastly different results. The carousel appears to be there but it's moving all of the content within the carousel div together, and when hitting the dots it shifts the screen. Can't seem to really find anything on this issue, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Html:

```
<head>  
 <link type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" />
 <link type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link type="text/css" href="styles/index.processed.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="wrapper">
  <div id="meet-cost-section">
    <h1 id="cost-title" class="title">Expansive Libary, at low a fee</h1>
    <div id="cost-carousel">
      <div class="cost-slide">
        <img class="cost-slide-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1353550/004-coins.svg" />

      </div>
      <div class="cost-slide">
        <img class="cost-slide-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1353550/003-open-book.svg" />

      </div>
      <div class="cost-slide">
        <img class="cost-slide-img" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/1353550/001-dislike.svg" />

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-migrate/3.0.1/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
 <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#meet-cost-section {
  padding: 4rem 0 5rem;
}

#cost-title {
  color: #185d48;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin: 0 auto 40px;
  width: 90%;
}

#cost-carousel {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.cost-slide {
  cursor: -webkit-grab;
  outline: none;
}

.cost-slide-img {
  margin: auto;
  width: 4rem;
}

.cost-slide-title {
  color: #185d48;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
}

.cost-slide-text {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: .75rem;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  line-height: 1.3rem;
}
```

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

     $('#cost-carousel').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        dots: true,
       arrows: false,
     });
});
```

A link to my [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mattlee3262/w52tftek/1/)

Comment: On the left side of jsfiddle, you can see a menu. Add your slick css and js links as External Resources, rather than calling them from HTML. Then it works as expected.

Comment: Ok, thanks I did that. In my local project though, it wasn't working. However I figured that out as well. Adding the CSS for Slick into my HTML wasn't working but importing it into my SCSS file did. Not sure if that is the correct way to do so, but it did work. Thanks, your help made it click in my head.